# Pycharm: add file to path

Tags: python, file, path

I am working with others on a python project which has subfolders.
I imported one file in another in the same subfolder and called it which worked just fine. Then I moved it to another subfolder and renamed it. In the file I want to call it, I changed

```
import file
```

to

```
from Subfolder import file
```

But now it doesn't work anymore. I get the error message

```
from Subfolder import file
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I guess after I moved the file, it is not properly in the project path any more, or something like this, but I can't figure out how to get it in again. 
Does anybody understand my problem and know what to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I should also mention that there is no __init__.py but I can import all the other files from that folder so that can't be the issue.

Comment: Hi, can you please add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It could be helpful to better understand your problem..

Comment: Please post your full code, as `SyntaxError` on that line very likely means an syntax error earlier in the code.

Comment: It can be the issue and it will be an issue. Without a __init__.py file, there is no module, and you cannot do `import` or `from import`. Also would be great to have the actual names you are using instead of these placeholders.

Comment: ok, thank you for your ansers. You are right, I should have been using the actual names as I figured out, it was somehow a filename, python doesn't want to work with. I don't know why, as it contained only letters and one number and the new name also contains letters and numbers, but somehow it works now.